# responsive stable background image in header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I was trying to convert PSD to Html and i got a little problem solving this issue. Take a look at the image below:

[image]

As I've mentioned with the red arrow, there is a blue background image in the header of the template! how can I add this background with a responsive and stable position even if the browser size changes? The background should always contain 70% of the screen (ends between the logo and the first nav-item).

Here is the jsfiddle of my work: https://jsfiddle.net/4dpgbLt9/2/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: IranSans, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  background: url("https://i.imgur.com/aN7jCZE.png") left no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.navbar {
  direction: rtl;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

.nav-item .nav-link {
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px !important;
}

.nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #ffd738 !important;
}

.nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #ffffff !important;
}

.nav-account-parent {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-account {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  top: -50px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: #025c64;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.navbar-brand img {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<html lang="en">

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-transparent justify-content-center">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gURHBju.png" alt="Logo">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">صفحه اصلی</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">درباره ما</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">درخواست مشاوره</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">خدمات</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">فروشگاه</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ارتباط با ما</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item nav-account-parent">
            <div class="nav-account"></div>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">ورود / عضویت</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="header">

  </div>
```

Thanks for your time ♥

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

1. Change `.header` `width` **from** `100vw` **to** `100%`
2. Change `background-size` **from** `contain` **to** `70%` **within** `.header`
3. **Add** `top` to `background:` to anchor it to the top left

CSS:

```
.header {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/aN7jCZE.png") top left no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-size: 70%;
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/CodeBoyCode/pen/VEEoQW